What is the relationship between these two merchants' marks?
I have attached the images of two Merchants' Marks, from around the year 1500. One is on a memorial stone in Dorchester Abbey, the other from Thame Church. Both of these are in Oxfordshire, about 11 miles apart.

The above is the one from Dorchester. It is on a memorial stone that is thought to be to a man called Robert Bedford, and his wife Alice. There was an inscription, in brass, on this stone, but that has since been lost. The source that claims this cites A catalogue of mediæval inscriptions in the Abbey Church of Dorchester Oxfordshire by Jerome Bertram - if anyone knows how to access this, or another way of knowing the inscription, that would be great. All that remains on the stone is the above shield.

This is the one in Thame Church. It is on a memorial to 'Geoffrey Dormer', a wool merchant of the Staple of Calais. It clearly includes his initials, GD.
I cannot help but notice that these two Merchants' Marks, from very close places at roughly the same time, are remarkably similar in appearance. Aside from the initials (which, I believe, come and go on Merchants' Marks), the only difference is a line across the left side of the forked base of the latter one, which is not present on the former.
I suppose my questions are as follows:

Is it possible these are variations on the same mark?
If so, why does the latter have that additional line?
Is it more likely that the stone in Dorchester is actually a stone to the Dormers, not the Bedfords?
If not, how come the families appear to have similar marks - what would be the link?
Does anyone know any other resources that may help my research?


You've missed one additional difference: the style of cross for the head. I have no idea what the difference means - but it would seem to be at least as significant as the one you point out.

I suppose I just dismissed that as a stylistic difference, kind of like the initials. The line across the base almost seems like an actual, substantial difference in the content. I do take your point, though - perhaps there is something in that. Thanks for your insight.

Do you have any sources/citations on merchant's marks?  I can't help to answer your question, but you've made me aware of a new potential historical source/method and I'd like to learn more.  If you've got anything, please update the question

https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1111/rest.12619 is an interesting read (Renaissance Studies Vol. 34 No. 2 DOI: 10.1111/rest.12619 Early modern merchant’s marks in medieval English manuscripts, Thomas Kittel)

And, earlier, https://www.hslc.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/62-2-Rylands.pdf - at the end are many marks, some looking not too different from the examples above yet coming from different places and times.

Jerome Bertrand appears to have authored quite a few books on mediæval brasses. The one you mention is at the British Library, and only there, apparently. But maybe one of his other books might mention the same marks? https://search.worldcat.org/search?q=au%3AJerome+Bertram&author=Bertram+Jerome%7CBertram%2C+Jerome%7CJerome+Bertram&limit=10&offset=81

The similarity of these two marks is noted in Dorchester Abbey, Oxfordshire: the archaeology and architecture of a cathedral, monastery and parish church by  Warwick Rodwell (Oxbow Books, 2009), in its section describing the floor slabs in the south chancel (p167, footnotes p170)

M.12 Purbeck marble indent for brasses of two standing figures on a rectangular inscription panel; also a single child below and a shield above. All the brasses are lost, except the shield which bears a merchant's mark of c. 1500. 48 It is fixed with a single rivet. The slab has been identified as probably belonging to Robert Bedford (d. 1491) and Alice Bedford; an inscription was recorded in 1574.49
48 This was not recorded in F.A. Girling, English Merchants' Marks (London, 1964). However, it is close to one on a brass in Thame church, belonging to Geoffrey Domer (d. 1502); ibid., p 42. See also: The Builder, 78, 13; Proc. Soc. Antiq. Lond., ser. 2, 12 (1887), 8.

Chasing up those final references, the  article in The Builder reproduces an image of the mark without saying anything substantial about it, but the one in Proceedings of the Society of Antiquaries of London is more interesting. It is from an oral presentation by J. G. Waller concerning these marks in general. He suggests several explanations for the elements of this mark -

The cross on top is a common element for many marks, and he believes this to be the "primitive form" of these as protective marks warding against evil.
The forked base is also common, and he identifies the Dorchester mark as "the simplest form".
The emanating chevrons are more controversial. Three possible reasons are that they are meant to be

streamers coming off the mast of a sailing ship (merchant-associated imagery)
a "symbol of the victory of Christ over death and the powers of Hades", again as a protective symbol
from the banner often shown in the image of the Holy Lamb (c.f. the famous Lamb and Flag pub in Oxford), perhaps linking it to wool merchants; or John the Baptist also has patronage over wool and has a banner association.



Waller prefers the interpretation that the streamers are part of the religious symbolism deriving from the idea that these marks are apotropaic in origin, rather than being linked to any specific merchant's occupation such as the wool trade.
As to the two marks in question, it may not be possible to establish with any certainty what is going on with their relationship. It does seem that family members sometimes used variations on one another's marks, but not in a very systematic way (as we do see with the formal system of heraldic differencing). There is also the possibility of a coincidence, as Waller seems to suggest that these comparatively simple marks are the most generic sort.
